# How to set attribute before form submit using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the form inside iframe, I need to set attribute before form get submit. Is it possible to set attribute before form submit using jquery. If yes, kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `src` of your `iframe` is on the same domain as your parent page then you should be able to do this. If not you will subject to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If its on a different domain then you will get permission denied errors no matter what you do.

The only way around this would be to build a local web page that would suck in the html of your iframe and then display it as if it was a page on your domain.

If your page is on the same domain then you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#idOfIframe").contents.find("#idOfFormHere").submit(function (e) {
    alert('mess with your form value here');

    if(youWantToStopSubmit == true) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){
//change action attribute of form
$(this).attr('action', '/um/abcd.php');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind form's `submit` to a function... The function will run before the form will submit.

```
$('#formName').bind('submit',setAttributes);

function setAttributes()
{
//Set attributes here...
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Firstly, you don't want the parentheses after `setAttributes` as a parameter to `bind`, and secondly you need the word `function` at the start of the function definition.

Comment: @James - Thank you! I was in a hurry, I've to go to the bathroom. Anyways, I've accepted the edit. Thanks!